# python program that scans a page for a specific combination of pixels?

Tags: python, image, screen, pixel, scanning

I'm trying to write a python program that will take a screen shot and then scan the image for a specific combination of pixels, or pattern. For example: it takes a screen shot of a web page and scans the whole image for a 10X10 pixel pattern. It would also be nice if it could record the x-y position of the image on the screen.

I searched the internet for hours for a solution but found nothing. I only know the basics of python and wouldn't know where to begin with this program.

Comment: That seems like a fairly complex program you're talking about, especially as one new to Python. And if when you say you "searched the internet for hours for a solution but found nothing" you mean a module or code snippit that already does this, perhaps you'll be stuck rolling your own. Why Python? Do you have expertise in a different language?

Comment: In more detail this is what I want it to do: First it takes a screen shot with image grab from the PIL module and saves it. Then it reads the image and looks for a specific rbg pixel pattern (from the saved screen shot). Thirdly, if it finds a match it will get the x-y location and then carry on with the rest of the code. I want it to do all of that in 30 seconds to a minute. I don't think it matters too much but I'm using windows, and I also figured out how to take a screenshot and save it already using PIL.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at some basic [pattern recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition) and [machine vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision) literature. In order to address your question considerably more detail is needed.

1. Is the pattern a binary image, a grayscale image, or a color image?
2. How often do you need to do this?
3. Have you looked at the Python Imaging Library ([PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/))?
4. How big of an image do you want to search?

A good course of action is to look at [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), and then look at [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) in [Fourier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Fast_convolution_algorithms) space to localize the target regions (relatively) quickly. Finally, a good [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=image%20processing%20python) search is your friend.

Comment: Indeed, not a trivial project.